# How to parse a JSON file line by line in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am working with very large JSON files, so I do not want to read the entire file and then iterate and parse each data entry.
Instead, I would like to iterate on the JSON file itself (for example: line-by-line/one object at a time).
I thought about holding the next line location as part of the current line data, so the JSON is a semi linked list, but I did not manage to extract a specific line from the JSON file.
Am I missing an easier way to achieve that? Is it even possible to extract and parse a specific line from a JSON file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should explain the real goal you want to archive. The solution you have in mind makes no sense for many reasons.

Comment: I have a giving situation of very large JSON files as inputs to the system, I wish to parse it. However, I do not think that holding all that massive amount of data in memory is the right way to go. Changing to another format is less of a possibility, as the JSONs are well integrated in the system.

Comment: You need only parts of the JSON? If not, building up the graph in memory might cause the bigger footprint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is not a line oriented format, so the idea of parsing "line by line" doesn't really make sense.

That said, there is at least one event-driven JSON parser for iOS that I know of, https://github.com/stig/json-framework. The built-in parser `NSJSONSerialization` only works on entire files.

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization` does support parsing a stream. See the documentation for `JSONObjectWithStream:options:error:`. Of course the result is still one giant object model.

Comment: While it does support parsing a stream - it won't provide any results or answers, until the stream is closed, and the full JSON data is available. You can't parse just partial JSON element a time using that.